# Unable to change root folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ftp, root

in my ftp panel i have two folders named "en.mediaconsul.it" and "mediaconsul.it"

I need to change the root folder so that [mediaconsult.it](https://mediaconsul.it) can point at a new wp installation, while preserving the old one.

This are the steps that I've made:

- I've installed the new wp in a folder named "new-site", in
  mediaconsul.it > public_html
- I've edited the default .htaccess file in mediaconsul.it > public_html, as follows:

> ```
> # BEGIN WordPress
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mediaconsul.it$ [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mediaconsul.it$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !new-site/
> RewriteRule (.*) /new-site/$1 [L]
> </IfModule>
> # END WordPress
> ```

Unfortunately the old site is still at [mediaconsult.it](https://mediaconsul.it), while the new one is at [mediaconsul.it/new-site](https://mediaconsul.it/new-site)

Comment: The response appears to be coming from an Nginx server, not Apache?! (`.htaccess` is an Apache config file - and won't work on Nginx.)

Comment: ... otherwise, if you are using Apache then what you have posted looks "OK". (Except that you should remove the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers and the `<IfModule>` wrapper.)

Comment: I've checked and, you are right, It's nginx. I'll try to contact the host (Siteground) since I don't think that i can access the nginx.conf file by myself. Am I right?

Comment: Hosting providers usually have installed an nginx plugin that interprets those apache style rewriting rules. But that is a crude hack, even the documentation explained that the need for such rules probably means that you did something wrong in your architecture.